# MSI GTX 660 Twin Frozer single 6 pin amperage

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, desktop-computer

I've just got MSI GTX 660 Twin Frozer and it has just a single 6 pin connector. My PSU has 2 x 12V rails 18 amps each. Can I run this card with this psu, are the connections suitable? The PSU is OCZ500SXS; how do I connect the card to it?

Comment: @Ramhound See the edit. The PSU is OCZ500SXS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OCZ StealthXStream OCZ500SXS 500W ATX12V / EPS12V Active PFC Power Supply](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817341012) has a 1 x 6-pin PCI-E connector.

> I've just got MSI GTX 660 Twin Frozr and it has just a single 6 pin
> connector.

The [MSI N660 TF 2GD5/OC G-SYNC Support GeForce GTX 660 2GB 192-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127699)  has a 6-pin PCI-E pin

[image]

[GeForce GTX 660 - Specifications](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-660/specifications)

> - Maximum Graphics Card Power (W): **140 W**
> - Minimum System Power Requirement (W): **450 W**
> - Supplementary Power Connectors: **One 6-pin**

The GTX 660 requires at a minimum requires a 450 W power supply

> how do I connect the card to it?

You connect the 6-pin connector to the card.

> Can I run this card with this psu

Yes

Answer (score 2):

Your power supply is of adequate power to run your graphics card. There is a 6-pin PCI-E connector connected to your PSU, it is labeled PCI-E and may actually be a 4-pin + 2-pin connector. THIS is the connector you will use to plug into the 6-pin port on the front of the graphics card.

Plugging in the connector into the graphics card and then turning on the PC and watching it boot is the next step.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.